# Which is more flexible for report RDLC or Crystal report? can i generate field name is rdlc without design view

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am developing an application which generates different types of report.
so I want to know which reporting tool is better. RDLC or Crystal report
and if I'm using RDLC can I generate Report fields from the code itself without using design interface of RDLC

Comment: Kinda opinion based. I find easier the MS product, and for really complex reports you cand add them .net functions

Comment: is it possible to generate fields without RDLC design Mode?

Comment: Im not sure about your use case, consider a [MCVE] of your problem.